# Creating Folder/Subfolder/File as specified in a text file, in a specific directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, shutil

I'm trying to create a sequence of folders which contains sub-folders which contains files with python.

The name of these folders come from a text file which has a list with the paths inside, like this:

```
songs\101_TNTOGCD\101_2020_CONTENT_LOOP_TNTOGCD.mov
songs\101_TNTOGCD\101_TNTOGCD_CONTENT_TC_A+B_CBLDESIGN2.mov
```

The number of the sub-folders it's not always the same, sometimes it can be two sub-folders and file, sometimes just one folder and file.

All of this must be created in a specified folder of my choice.

This is what I did so far:

```
import os
import shutil
import os.path

with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\textfile.txt", "r") as g:
    lines = g.readlines()

base_path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3"
mov_origin = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\file_000.mov"
for line in lines:
    target = base_path
    path = line.split("\\")
    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        target += path[i]
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            os.makedirs(target)
        else:
            pass
        target += "\\"
    target += path[-1].replace("\n", "")
    print(target)
    shutil.copyfile(mov_origin, target)
```

But basically, when I run it, nothing happens.
I didn't get any error, but nothing is created.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

UPDATE: The code was not working because of my mistake in the Run/Debug configuration in PyCharm. The wrong Script Path was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was working. The issue happened because of my mistake in the Run/Debug configuration in PyCharm. The wrong Script Path was selected.

Comment: Remember to accept it too, it shows others you are happy with the result. Good work!

Comment: It doesn't let me accept it before two days, I guess it's a matter of privileges? I will do it for sure as soon as I can. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give it something to open. The line

```
with open("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx.txt", "r") as g:
```

cannot do anything unless you have folders actually called XXXX... etc.
What does it do when you have a proper file path in there?

When I tried this it printed the lines that are within that text file. I would liberally use print statements until you see where the issue is.

```
import os
import shutil
import os.path
#lines = []
with open("/Users/.../Desktop/OPW_DATA/comments.txt", "r") as g:
    lines = g.readlines()

base_path = "/Users/.../Desktop/"
#mov_origin = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\file_000.mov"
for line in lines:
    print('line:', line)
    target = base_path
    print('target:',target)
    path = line.split("\\")
    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        target += path[i]
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            os.makedirs(target)
        else:
            pass
        target += "\\"
    target += path[-1].replace("\n", "")
    print(target)
    #shutil.copyfile(mov_origin, target)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I changed my actual path with xxxx just for privacy reasons. In my code, there is proper folders path and so on.

Comment: I just post my directory and substitute a ... for anything that needs to be kept private. It gives a better idea of what the code is supposed to look like.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I will change it.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide something that shows that your code is doing something.

Comment: Change your title to better reflect the problem. It is better to have a traceback that shows the issue too. there are many highly experienced people on here who can quickly diagnose what is the issue if they can see a declaration of the problem and a traceback.

Comment: fyi when I first pose a question I am completely in the dark as to what the problem may be. Often there will be a hint in a comment that gets me part of the way there. At that point it is often worth redefining the problem in the title and question body, it makes it quicker for someone else to see if they can help - my own original question titles are often too nebulous. A more precise question and traceback gets answered quicker, though I do appreciate that is not often possible. Reducing the problem to something simpler, or breaking it up often helps too.

Comment: it may be to do with the "//" not being escaped?

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help so far! I will try to make it better.

Comment: Post your own answer so that anyone else with a similar issue gets helped.

Comment: Added the resolution for the "not working code" in the description of the issue.